# How to explain the sample space of Monty Hall problem?

Tags: probability

I am now pretending to be a newbie student. I write the following sample space for the Monty Hall problem (It is a famous brain teaser, I assume you know it).

$$
S=\{
(C,G1),(C,G2), (G1,G2), (G2,G1)
\}
$$

where the first tuple represents the first choice taken by the guest and the second tuple represents the optional switch  offered by the host.

As a teacher I have difficulty to explain that $\{(C,G1),(C,G2)\}$ must be simplified to just one $\{(C,G)\}$ and $n(S)=3$. $C$ is the car, $G1$ and $G2$  are the goats.

Do you have any idea to explain it?

## Edit

More information:

- for $(C,G1)$, if you switch you will lose
- for $(C,G2)$, if you switch you will lose
- for $(G1,G2)$, if you switch you will win
- for $(G2,G1)$, if you switch you will win

Comment: [Not quite an answer, but] I think of the **initial** sample space as being: goat, goat, car. (Picking here gives you a 1 in 3 chance of finding the car: 3 choices, random.) Once the contestant picks one of these, there is now more information; specifically, a goat is revealed. So the **modified** sample space is: goat, car. (Picking here - i.e., swiching - gives you a 1 in 2 chance of finding the car: 2 choices, random.) The parenthetical remarks here are how I, personally, understand that switching is wise: for winning probabilities, 1/2 > 1/3.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: But you win 2/3 of the time by switching!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key here is that $(C, G_1)$ and $(C, G_2)$ are each only half as likely as each of the other two cases - and the standard "counting" approach to probability only works if all the cases are equally likely. To fix it, you need a third event - think of it as Monty flipping a coin. If it comes up heads, he picks the leftmost goat that's still hidden; if tails, the rightmost. If the player picks a goat, the coin flip doesn't matter, but it happens anyway. This gives us six outcomes: $(C, H, G_1), (C, T, G_2), (G_1, H, G_2), (G_1, T, G_2), (G_2, H, G_1), (G_2, T, G_1)$.

Comment: The fact that the coin flip doesn’t matter in the initial-goat cases corresponds to the crucial part of the setup that Monty *knows* where the car is and actively avoids it.  This avoidance conveys information, which is how you can win so often.  A Monty with no information can reveal none, but must sometimes ruin the game by revealing the car.